# Image loses effect of CamanJS on manipulate canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I have a canvas, which handle images drawn on it with the [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/) plugin and it works perfectly. But if I manipulate the canvas manually (without the aid of plugin) the image loses its effect. For example, if I add a filter (Vintage, for example) to the image, works perfectly, but if I turn the canvas, using `translate` and `scale` the canvas is reversed but the image loses its effect. It seems that with each change in the image through the plugin, it saves its current state, and therefore, the effect is lost after a change without using it. How to do this while preserving the effects of the image?

To add to the effect, use the same examples of the plugin site, since the code to reverse the canvas is (*scripts.js*):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html, body").on("click", "#vintage", function() {
        Caman("#filtrar", function() {
            this.vintage().render();
        });
    });

    $("html, body").on("click", "#inverter_foto", function() {
        var c = $("#filtrar")[0];

        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        ctx.translate(filtro_width, 0);
        ctx.scale(-1, 1);
        ctx.drawImage(filtro, 0, 0);
    });
});
```

The `filtro_width` variables and `filtro` correspond to the image drawn on the canvas.

on HTML:

```
<canvas id="filtrar" width="640" height="255"></canvas>

<button id="vintage">Vintage Effect</button>
<button id="inverter_foto">Reverse</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/caman.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: @Kaiido I editted the question with an example.

Comment: But, the code to add a effect is the same of http://camanjs.com/examples/ (buttons below) and to reverse the canvas is the code on the question. That is all and only the code that is part of the question

Comment: how about applying camanjs 's effect again after reversing the canvas?

Comment: Edited again, @Kaiido

Comment: @jack3694078 If I apply the effect again after reversing the canvas, he applies the effect and loses its inversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do manipulate the canvas outside of the Caman library, you need to use the [`reloadCanvasData`](http://camanjs.com/api/classes/Caman.html#reloadCanvasData-instance) method to reinitialize the imageData stored in the Caman object, otherwise, it only uses the first one + what it updated itself.

```js
vintage.onclick = function() {
  Caman("#filtrar", function() {
    this.vintage().render();
  });
};

inverter_foto.onclick = function() {

  var c = $("#filtrar")[0];

  var clone = c.cloneNode(true);
  var ctx = clone.getContext("2d");

  ctx.translate(c.width, 0);
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0);

  var oCtx = c.getContext('2d');
  oCtx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  oCtx.drawImage(clone, 0, 0);

  if(check.checked){
    Caman("#filtrar", function() {
      this.reloadCanvasData();
    });
   }
};

var filtro = new Image();
filtro.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
var filtro_width = filtrar.width / 2;
filtro.onload = function() {
  filtrar.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, filtrar.width, filtrar.height);
};
filtro.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.1.2/caman.full.js"></script>
<p>First revert the image then apply the effect</p>
<button id="inverter_foto">Reverse</button>
<button id="vintage">Vintage Effect</button>
reloadCanvasData<input id="check" type="checkbox" checked/>

<canvas id="filtrar" width="640" height="255"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! (please wait 12 hours for me to deliver his reward)